# How can save a screenshot

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I want to take a screenshot and save it after I click a button. Here's my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ViewGroup viewgroup = new LinearLayout(this);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(1);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ));
        btn.setText("aaaa");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        viewgroup.addView(btn);
        viewgroup.addView(new PaintView(this));
        setContentView(viewgroup);
    }
}
```

I've added permissions on the manifest as such:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file, add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and add this attribute to the `application` tag

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

In activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                } else {
                    takeScreenshot();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //**if you want to open this screenshot
            openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```